# How to stop upload to Google Cloud Storage if file already exists using PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm having a problem with GAE and GCS.

I'm trying to upload a file, which works - but I can't seem to stop the upload if the file already exists. It just gets a random temp name.

I have this code, but it doesn't do the job.

```
<?php
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

SESSION_START();

$gs_new_name = $_FILES["uploaded_files"]['name'];
$image = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl("gs://bucket/".$gs_new_name, true);

if(getimagesize($image) !== FALSE){
    $gs_name = $_FILES["uploaded_files"]['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($gs_name, "gs://bucket/".$gs_new_name);
} else{
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: `getimagesize()` returns either array or false, not integer.

Comment: I startet out using that, and just echoed "yay" or "nay", and that seemed to work. But I'll try, thanks.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, i tried using "is_array", still no luck. It still continues the upload with the random name.

Comment: p.s. you can use `var_dump()` to get the contents. And be sure to read the [manual](http://php.net/getimagesize) of `getimagesize()`. But I think `if(getimagesize($image) !== FALSE)` is sufficient.

Comment: No luck. Maybe it's not possible to stop the upload because of GAE's way of uploading. @ShivanRaptor

Comment: the real "upload" method is `move_uploaded_file()`, which moves uploaded temp file to correct location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** possible to *stop* an upload to GCS through PHP. When uploading directly to GCS via `CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl()` the entire HTTP request is sent to the GCS proxy which handles the upload and then forwards the request back to your App Engine application. At that time PHP adds the location of the upload file on GCS to the `$_FILES` array. As such the current approach of executing `die()` would not work since the entire upload has already been performed prior to the execution of your script.

Short of checking client side (via JavaScript) for a particular filename/extension (plenty of topics on that) I am not sure how you would do something like this. I am also not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish. Are you simply looking to restrict files to image types only? If so checking the extension on client side and then performing a check similar to the one you have should do the trick. Only instead of calling `die()` you could call `unlink($gs_name)` to remove the temporary file.

Comment: Thanks! This was great. I was just trying to make sure two files with the same name couldn't be uploaded :)