# How to cancel file upload/download in C++ Client Libraries for Google Cloud Services

Tags: c++, google-cloud-storage

I use google [cloud cpp library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp) to upload/download a file, using **UploadFile** and **DownloadToFile** methods accordingly.

How it possible to **cancel** a file transfer from another thread?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short answer is that is not possible. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399869/how-to-stop-upload-to-google-cloud-storage-if-file-already-exists-using-php) with a similar question. The bottom line is the same for all the Client Libraries. Is not possible to stop an upload to GCS through any client libraries. You will find further information on the post above. I also attach this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455769/gcp-storage-do-files-appear-before-upload-is-complete) where it explains the consistency of uploads in GCS. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (currently) to cancel a download in progress. But you could write something like this that is easy to cancel:

```
void MyDownload(
    gcs::Client client, std::string bucket_name, std::string object_name,
    std::string filename, bool& canceled) {
  auto reader = client.ReadObject(bucket_name, object_name);
  auto writer = std::ofstream(filename);
  std::vector<char> buffer(4 * 1024 * 1024L);
  do {
    if (canceled) return; // TODO - not thread safe
    reader.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    writer.write(buffer.data(), reader.gcount());
  } while(not reader.eof() and reader.good() and writer.good());
}
```